# Why does "Legend" not styled in ie8?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

```
<form class="form" id="profile_form">
   <legend>Your profile</legend>
     <div class="control-group ">
         <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
         <div class="controls">
         <input type="text" id="phone" class="span5">
         <div class="help-block phone_not_confirmed need_confirm">
          To confirm your phone number, please check for a text message from us.
         </div>
         <label class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" id="phone_visible">
           Display my phone number to the public
         </label>
       </div>
     </div>
```

.... ....

In IE8, the text "your profile" appears, but it is unstyled. Note: I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Styling for Ie8  legend http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?692660-Internet-Explorer-8-and-Legend-Styling

Comment: It's invalid markup without a `fieldset`...anything is fair game. If you don't need a `fieldset`, then simply use something like `<div class="form-legend"></div>` and style that.

Answer (score 7):

There is a weird behavior in IE. IE7 & IE8 closes the legend element it encounters when it’s not inside a fieldset element and move it’s contents out to an adjacent text node.

Therefore, a workaround would be to wrap your legend in a fieldset.

Source: http://html5doctor.com/legend-not-such-a-legend-anymore/

Answer (score 5):

IE8 was released before HTML5 was invented. Therefore, it knows nothing of HTML5 rules, and sticks with the HTML4 rules.

Under the HTML4 rules, the `<legend>` tag is only valid when it is a child of a `<fieldset>` tag.

Therefore you code is being seen by IE8 as invalid markup. Once you've got invalid markup, you can't guarantee what the browser is going to do.

Under HTML5, the rule about it being inside a `<fieldset>` no longer applies, so modern browsers should be fine with it. But older browsers like IE8 are likely to struggle.

If you need to support IE8, my advice would be to use a `<div>` or other generic tag instead, or to wrap it in a `<fieldset>` if it's semantic to do so (which it is in this case).